# GET form action with URL parameter gets removed on form submission

Tags: html, forms, url, get

This doesn't go to the URL `http://example.com/a.php?r=1&go=1`.  Instead it goes to `http://example.com/a.php?go=1` .

```html
<form method="GET" action="a.php?r=1">
    <input type="radio" name="go" value="1">
</form>
```

Even if I clear `action=""` it again goes to the same wrong URL.  How can I include the `r=1` in the URL of the form submission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `method="get"`, you can't put values in the query string of the `action`. They will be replaced by the values from the form fields when you post the form.

Put the values in hidden fields instead:

```
<form method="GET" action="a.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="r" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="go" value="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Passing additional parameters is done with hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="r" value="1" />
```

(sorry, i edited it; it didn't take my code on the first attempt)

Comment: But I want to have type="radio"

Comment: @pzztzz: What do you mean? You can, of course, use radio as you did before. Just add <input type="hidden" name="r" value="1" /> to specify the "r" parameter.